# Cycles GPU render duration estimate is 7h before restarting computer and 4 mins after

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I'm having trouble for past few months with rendering. To adress the issue right, I have a scene that I'm able to render in 4 minutes (Cycles, 400 samples). But as I keep using the computer, like playing a game or only leaving it on for few hours and I reopen the blender file and press render, it lags as hell and says approx time 7 hours. It also completely lags my system. But when I restart the computer it works without an issue and renders in 4 minutes again. I ran system diagnostics (RAM, watched GPU / CPU usage), reinstalled windows and the issue still persists.

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Yeah I'm glad that you are trying to tell me to change the title, I'm not native speaker nor I can't think of a simple way of describing the issue to put it in a title so someone can actually understand clearly where the issue is.